# How can we handle in app message card while running automation using selenium-java

Tags: java, selenium, browserstack

1. After installing .apk file on android device
2. In app msg card will be displayed on screen
3. without closing this in app msg we are not able to run further automation sequence

Note : I am using browserstack for app automation

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3QzmJ.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Pop-ups are enabled by default in browserstack for Chrome (as the pop-up blocker is disabled, by default).

You can disable it:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setExperimentalOption("excludeSwitches",Arrays.asList("disable-popup-blocking"));
caps.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
```